# Regex to identify numbers only if its followed by \r or \n it shoiuld not match

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying a regex which just identifies number but if its followed by new line or carriage return it should not match
For example 3 is valid match

```
3\n
```

does not match

Desc - users copy a value and paste it but when user is copying if new line characters are copied we should invalidate it. \r and \n are mistakenly copied by user from editor.

\d+ is not doing the trick as it is not considering newline.

Comment: Can you give some more examples of what is valid and what is invalid.  I'm guessing you have the numbers and \r\ns in a string?

Comment: No actually users copy a value and paste it but when user is copying if new line characters are copied we should invalidate it. \r and \n are mistakenly copied by user from editor.

Comment: Are you looking for a single digit number? or just to take out every single instance of \n?

Comment: Use a lookahead:  `string pattern = @"\d+(?!\r?\n)";`

Comment: @KennethK. [`\d+(?!\r?\n)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b%28%3f!%5cr%3f%5cn%29&i=345+3456%0d%0a345) will match *partially* a 2+ digit chunk at the end of the line. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47827764/3832970) for a correct regex based solution.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47827764/3832970)?

Answer (score 1):

> `\d+` is not doing the trick as it is not considering newline

That is true, one usually uses [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to take into account context, or capturing groups coupled with backreferences in the replacement patterns (when replacing, as in this case).

Here is one way to match all digit chunks not followed with `\r` or `\n`:

```
\d+(?![\r\n\d])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%28%3F!%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5Cd%5D%29&i=345%203456%0D%0A345).

**Details**

- `\d+` -  1+ digits (to only match ASCII digits, use `[0-9]` or pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag to the regex compile method)
- `(?![\r\n\d])` - a [**negative lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is a digit, CR or LF symbols immediately to the right of the current location.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/q8NvaQ):

```
var s = "3 45 123\r 456\n 434554645\r\n 000";
var pattern = @"\d+(?![\r\n\d])";
var results = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", string.Join(", ", results));
// => Result: 3, 45, 000
```

Another fancy regex is [`(?>\d+)(?![\r\n])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3e%5cd%2b%29%28%3f!%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%29&i=345+3456%0d%0a345), where the `(?>\d+)` is an atomic group allowing no backtracking into its pattern, and thus there is no longer need to check for a digit on the right.